# Camel iMap - ignore SSL certificat

Tags: ssl, apache-camel, jakarta-mail, imap, blueprint-osgi

i'm using imap endpoint and i try to ignore SSL certificat by using:

the First class DummySSLSocketFactory :

```
    public class DummySSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
        private SSLSocketFactory factory;
        public DummySSLSocketFactory() {
            try {
                SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
                sslcontext.init(null,
                                     new TrustManager[] { new

DummyTrustManager()},
                                 null);
            factory = (SSLSocketFactory)sslcontext.getSocketFactory();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            // ignore
        }
    }

    public static SocketFactory getDefault() {
        return new DummySSLSocketFactory();
    }

    public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
        return factory.createSocket();
    }

    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String s, int i, boolean flag)
                                throws IOException {
        return factory.createSocket(socket, s, i, flag);
    }

    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress inaddr, int i,
                                InetAddress inaddr1, int j) throws IOException {
        return factory.createSocket(inaddr, i, inaddr1, j);
    }

    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress inaddr, int i)
                                throws IOException {
        return factory.createSocket(inaddr, i);
    }

    public Socket createSocket(String s, int i, InetAddress inaddr, int j)
                                throws IOException {
        return factory.createSocket(s, i, inaddr, j);
    }

    public Socket createSocket(String s, int i) throws IOException {
        return factory.createSocket(s, i);
    }

    public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
        return factory.getDefaultCipherSuites();
    }

    public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
        return factory.getSupportedCipherSuites();
    }
}
```

the second class DummyTrustManager :

```
public class DummyTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] cert, String authType) {
        // everything is trusted
    }

    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] cert, String authType) {
        // everything is trusted
    }

    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return new X509Certificate[0];
    }
}

the third class AllowAll to set java mail propeties:

public class AllowAll {
         public void setsslproperties()  {

                 //DummySSLSocketFactory easy = new EasySSLProtocolSocketFactory();
                 Properties props = System.getProperties();
                 props.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
             props.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.socketFactory.class","com.mycompany.imapssl.DummySSLSocketFactory");
                 props.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
                 props.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.port", "993");
                 Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);

        }

}
```

How can i associate this to the iMap EiP to ignore SSL Certificate ?

this is the route:

```
<route id="timerToLog">
    <from uri="imaps://server:993?username=user_name&password=pass"/>
    <log message="ok"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a recent version of JavaMail, set the [mail.imap.ssl.trust](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/package-summary.html) property to the name of the host you want to trust.  That avoids the need to create your own socket factory.